# Phonegap build how do you add plugins to app

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

The document says:

"There are two steps to including a plugin in your project:

Importing the native code using the config.xml

**Referencing the JavaScript code for the plugin**"

http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_plugins.md.html#importing-native

And to reference you do this in your html file:

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="barcodescanner.js"></script>  <-this
```

However, how do you know what to put in place of barcodescanner.js.

In fact i don't know about work flow of including plugins if i am using solely using  **phonegap build** to build and test my app and not use anything local. I tried including plugin using cli. But that didn't update root `config.xml`. So i manually put the code config.xml, as can be found https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1163 . But on this page there was no mentioning of what to include in javascript file. do i use acceleration.js, device-motion.js

Answer (score 4):

if you want to include the bar code scanner with phonegap build you coulde do the following,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id          = "com.phonegap.example"
    versionCode = "10"
    version     = "1.0.0" >

    <!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

    <name>PhoneGap Example</name>

    <description>
      An example for phonegap build docs.
    </description>

    <author href="https://build.phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">
      Hardeep Shoker
    </author>

    <!-- We'll include the Barcode plugin as an example -->
    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration"/>

</widget>
```

This is an example config.xml file to include in the same directory as your homepage. In the javascript file you don't include any scripts for plugins(make sure

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

is included). Just call the plugin methods and build will handle the rest for you.For example I have included the vibration plugin above. If I wanted my phone to vibrate I would simply call a function like this,

```
function test(){
    navigator.notification.vibrate(1000);

}
```

There is no need for anything like,

```
<script src="barcodescanner.js"></script>
```

Just make sure the plugin is referenced in the config.xml file and everything should be ok