# Phonegap build plugin. How to implement?

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I need to make a simple Android application for school project using Phonegap build and with one Phonegap plugin. Easiest seems to be vibration plugin. I did it like in this thread (in answer is a part about vibration plugin):

[Phonegap build how do you add plugins to app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318653/phonegap-build-how-do-you-add-plugins-to-app?rq=1)

So there is a part of code I already have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
      <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
        <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

        <script src="cordova.js"></script>

        <script>
           function onBodyLoad(){
               document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
           }


           function onDeviceReady(){
           }
        </script>

        <script>

            function onKlick(){
            navigator.notification.vibrate(1000);
            }
        </script>


     </head>


        <body onload="onBodyLoad();">

        <div data-role="page" id="secPage">

           <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

              <input type="button" onclick="onKlick();" value="Vibrate Me!">

           </div>

        </div>      

    </body>

</html>
```

And config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns= "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
xmlns:gap= "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
id= "apk_1"
versionCode= "1"
version = "1.0.0" >


   <name>Apk 2015</name>
   <description>blah, blah, blah</description>
   <author>AK</author>

      <gap:platform name="android" />

      <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration"/>


</widget>
```

Of course problem is that it is not working. There is a button but without response. As You surely see I'm a total beginner in JS and jQuery, so I'll be very appreciated for Your help :)

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors in your javascript console? This is one of the first things to check.

Comment: I checked and there is an error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'vibrate' of undefined**. It's the line with **" navigator.notification.vibrate(1000);"**. There is also error **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier** but on a blank spot, without any code, so i supose it's nothing

Comment: Vibrate will always be undefined in the browser. You need to test it on your phone. Install it on the phone and then check the console by running the app whilst the phone is plugged in and using Chrome inspect to see any errors in the console. I'd put the onKlick function in the onDeviceReady function too.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I was thinking he was using Ripple. My bad.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that you're missing some of the default cordova plugins. Check your plugins folder, underneath your app directory. If it's blank (and I suspect it is) from a command line (underneath your app directory) run ....

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.vibration
```

You might have this plugin installed already, and if so, remove it, and re-add it.

You might need to install some other core plugins, such as:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs
```

This answer might lead you down the trail to fixing your issue. Hope it helps!

Comment: He is using PhoneGap Build, not PhoneGap. Your instructions are only relevant for PhoneGap. PGB plugins are not installed in that way.

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand that, and would like to. I thought PG and PGB both could utilize native Cordova plug-ins now? http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_plugins.md.html#Plugins. If he follows these plug-in installation instructions from PGB, wouldn't it be the same deal? Effectively ensuring the plug-in tag is in the config.xml.

Comment: It's far easier to use the PGB method of you're using PGB. If you use CLI stuff too you can, as many users are reporting, get some serious problems.